# Embeding Any Type of View into a TextView Without NSTextAttachmentViewProvider

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am an intern at a company in which I was assigned to embed a YoutubePlayer into a UITextView. So far, our solution is to Embed a Youtube Thumbnail and add it into the TextView using NSAttributed String, and when clicked it goes into another view that displays the Youtube Video. This behavior is something that we do not expect.

I came across NSTextAttachmentViewProvider that attached a view into UITextView, it's great, but not what we need. I also encounter a library that supports it, but it's unproven so we decide not to use it.

Are there a way for me to embed any type of view into UITextView without Using NSTextAttachement? NSAttributedString does not support what we need currently (or perhaps I'm missing something)

Thank you

Comment: No there isn't. If the third party code that you saw is visible, you might want to replicate it, but currently, there is nothing done as such.

Comment: so basically, we need to create a whole new custom UITextView and a custom NSTectAttachment? if that so then, our pm would be hella mad hahahaha

Comment: I'm trully sorry, turns out it;s not nsattachment that only support ios 15+ , the name is "NSTextAttachmentViewProvider"

Comment: If your `UITextView` doesn't scroll, you might find the place of your "video", and add a video view there. You can also use `exclusionPaths` if needed. Else, I'd guess it's playing with low level CoreText APIs.

Comment: too bad it's scrollable and we have no idea how the user will place the video player (because it's a forum typish app). Didn't know you need to access a very low-level library to solve it. thank you for your solutions

Comment: "I also encounter a library that supports it, but it's unproven so we decide not to use it." Which third party lib did you found for that? "unproven": you don't want to use third party, or it doesn't work?

Comment: this one https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView , it worked (at least on my personal project), but it's unproven for production and has not been updated since 2020

Comment: So you can see the code, so understand it/debug it, and you can mimic it.